# Euler 19 Output

Tags: c

This is for Project Euler 19. I pretty much figured the code out, but my output is +1 for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 12

    int main(void)
    {
            int year;
            int month;
            int daysinmonths[SIZE] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
            int currentday = 365; /* Account for 1900 */
            int sundaycount = 0;

        for (year = 1901; year <= 2000; year++) {
                if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
                        daysinmonths[1] = 29;
                }
                for (month = 0; month < SIZE; month++) {
                        if (currentday % 7 == 0)
                                sundaycount++;
                        currentday += daysinmonths[month];
                }
        }
        printf("%d Sundays as the first of a month from 1901 to 2000 \n", sundaycount);
   }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you described what Euler 19 is, to save everyone a search. Also what does "my output is +1" mean?

Comment: The output is supposed to be 171, but I got 172, thus +1. Euler 19 asks us to find how many Sundays are the first of the month from 1901 to 2000.

Comment: The first time you encounter a leap year, you set the February day count to 29.  Where do you set it back to 28?

Comment: I just added the else line to set it back to 28 
else
         daysinmonths[1] = 28;
It still produces the same result though.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? Is the first Sunday [September 1901](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1901&country=1)?

Comment: Yes the first Sunday is September 1901, and 1901 has 2 Sundays as the first day of a month.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 12

    int main(void)
    {
            int year;
            int month;
            int daysinmonths[SIZE] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
            int currentday = 366; /* Account for 1900 */
            int sundaycount = 0;

        for (year = 1901; year <= 2000; year++) {
                if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
                        daysinmonths[1] = 29;
                }
                else{
                    daysinmonths[1] = 28;
                }
                for (month = 0; month < SIZE; month++) {
                        if (currentday % 7 == 0){
                                sundaycount++;
                        }
                        currentday += daysinmonths[month];
                }
        }
        printf("%d Sundays as the first of a month from 1901 to 2000 \n", sundaycount);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem. It seems like I should assign the first day to 366.

Comment: I think that's right.  1900 was *not* a leap year, but Jan 1, 1900 was a Monday, not a Sunday.  I.e. Dec. 31 1899 was a Sunday.  Add 365 to that and you have Dec. 31, 1900.  Add 366 to that and you have Jan 1, 1901 as desired.